# Python- For Loop of Iter and enumerate list

Tags: python

I have a list defined and it gets iter() applied to it. It then goes through a for loop and inside the for loop it gets enumerate(). I want it to print out the output 4 times because it is in the range of 4. Can anyone look and see what the problem might be? I

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_1 = iter(list_1)

for x in range(2):
    for y,z in enumerate(list_1):
        print(str(y)+" "+str(z))
```

output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

desired output:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: remove the line `list_1 = iter(list_1)`.

Comment: When you use the `iter` function you create an iterable that is consumed. So after the first `range` iteration there is nothing left in `list_1`.

Comment: `iter(..)` generates an iterator over the list. That means at the end of the outer `for` loop, the iterator is "exhausted". so the second time you enter the `for`, there are no elements in it anymore.

Comment: (I'm also trying to find the duplicate that asks "why is my result empty after iterating twice?")

Comment: @timgeb, I think I found a good target, but feel free to change / add.

Comment: What if I need it to be iterable... how would i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Python [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) is **iterable**. 
You don't need to use `iter()`.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

for x in range(2):
    for y,z in enumerate(list_1):
        print(str(y)+" "+str(z))
```

**Out:**

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: I'm just using this as an example. I need my list to be iterable.. How could I do this while making my list iterable?

Comment: @S.McWhorter I'm not sure I see you. You wan't iterate an object which is use iter() in any way?